# how to Access My host machine localhost from vmware mac

Tags: asp.net, windows, macos, virtual-machine, ionic4

I need to debug my APIs made by visual studio using vm mac

So i need to access localhost in the parent or Host machine from the Guest Machine **without publishing the project**

**Host Machine ==> Windows 10**

**Guest Machine ==> Mac os 10.14**

Can any one help me?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it by BINDING My IP To the project applicationhost.config file

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1806:192.168.88.47" />
```

and using it as default [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzgK2.png)